# Is it necessary to secure the secret (e.g., key) in the .so file?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, apk, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

A private key has been #define in the C code of .so file. This key is used for the customized authentication process between client-server.

In some [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQRF1aPXhgw) and [blog](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/how-to-decompile-linux-so-library-files-from-a-ms-windows-os), people show how to disassemble .so file using IDA as well as extract function information. The output should be assembly language. **How difficult to extract the key value from such output?**

If the answer is the key defined in .so also needs protection, do I need to apply obfuscation on the C code before converting it to .so? Whether the normal algorithm will be affected for C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and for skilled reverse engineer it is more or less easy. Obfuscating the secret key only slows down the hacker, but don't give you 100% protection. Consider using certificates signed by some authority.